# Remote PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, publishing-site, site-template, backup, site

I have server 1 (application that the script) (dax-sp) and server 2 (sharepoint) (sp-sp)

Script on server 1 (ScriptStart.ps1)

```
 Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2000
 $pwd = Get-Content C:\crd-sharepoint.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
 $crd = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "spadmin",$pwd
 Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ssi-sp -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $crd
 Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
 C:\Script\SPSiteCreator.ps1
```

Script on server 2 (SPSiteCreator.ps1)

```
$dax = Import-Csv C:\dax2.csv
    ForEach ( $dax2 in $dax ) {
    $Number = $dax2.Number
    $Descrip = $dax2.Descrip
    }
function SendMail($Tipic, $msg) {
  $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
  $message.Subject = $Tipic
  $message.Body = $msg
  $message.To.Add("admin@sp.lab")
  $message.From = "sharepoint@sp.lab"     
  $client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient -ArgumentList "sp-exch.sp.lab"
  $client.Send($message)
} 
$test = (Get-SPWeb http://ssi-sp/projects/$Number -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null
If ($test -ne "True") {
New-SPWeb -url http://ssi-sp/projects/$Number -template OFFILE#1 -name "$Number"
Import-SPWeb http://ssi-sp/projects/$Number -Path C:\Backup\ssi-sp-projects-project_05-11-2012.bak
Get-SPWeb http://ssi-sp/projects/$Number | Set-SPWeb -Description "$Descrip"
$web = (get-spweb http://ssi-sp/projects/$Number)
$web.Title = "$Number"
$web.Update()
} Else{
SendMail -Tipic "SP Error" -msg "SharePoint Site $Number error"
}
```

I used

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

on both servers and

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role Server
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer sp-sp
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | out-file C:\crd-sharepoint.txt
```

on server 1

Errora with i recive

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="3762507597" Machine="sp-sp"><f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="microsoft.powershell" path="C:\Windows\system32\pwrshplugin.dll"></f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault> For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

or

```
New-SPWeb : Reported an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
At C:\Script\SPSiteCreator.ps1:8 char:10
+ New-SPWeb <<<<  -url http://sp-sp/projects/$Number -template OFFILE#1 -name "$Number"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletNewWeb:SPCmdletNewWeb) [New-SPWeb], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWeb

Import-SPWeb : Reported an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
At C:\Script\SPSiteCreator.ps1:10 char:13
+ Import-SPWeb <<<<  http://sp-sp/projects/$Number -Path C:\Backup\sp-projects-project_05-11-2012.bak
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], OutOf
   MemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWeb
```

The idea of all this is that I have from one server to execute script to create pages based on the backup site.